# Compare Datetimes

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Why that `if` condition, comparing two datetime, doens't work?
If they need to be `NSDate`, how can I convert them?

Code:

```
if ([[NSDate date] dateStringFromFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"] > [self.tfDatetime dateStringFromFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"]) {
    // Do ...something
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare two NSDates(say, dateOne and dateTwo), use this

```
switch ([dateOne compare:dateTwo]){
     case NSOrderedAscending:
          NSLog(@"NSOrderedAscending");
    break;
    case NSOrderedSame:
          NSLog(@"NSOrderedSame");
    break;
    case NSOrderedDescending:
         NSLog(@"NSOrderedDescending");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Do you now how can I add an `AlertView` inside a `case`? Im getting the error `Expected expression`.

Comment: switch ([dateOne compare:dateTwo]){
     case NSOrderedAscending:{
UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:@"Alert" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [alertView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
}

Answer (score 3):

there is a method defined for this. Try the below code to do compare two dates :)

```
switch ([[[NSDate date] dateStringFromFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"] compare [self.tfDatetime dateStringFromFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"]]){
    case NSOrderedAscending:
         NSLog(@"NSOrderedAscending");
    break;
    case NSOrderedSame:
         NSLog(@"NSOrderedSame");
    break;
    case NSOrderedDescending:
         NSLog(@"NSOrderedDescending");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Do you now how can I add an `AlertView` inside a `case`? Im getting the error `Expected expression`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to compare dates would be checking interval between the 2 dates like this, `if ([date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2] > 0)`. `date1` is latest date.

I am comparing 2 `NSDate`s like this.

```
if ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]])
{
    // Do something
}
```

I don't get any error. You are comparing 2 `NSString`s which will be a problem because there is not such method for `NSString`.

Comment: Error: `NSString` may not respond to `timeIntervalSinceDate:`

Comment: Do you want to compare 2 `NSString`s, or 2 `NSDate`s? You said you want to compare `NSDate`s. Go read up on the class references. Don't down vote without understanding the classes and methods involved.

Comment: In the post Im clear that Im trying to compare two `NSStrings`, and if needed, how can I convert them to `NSDate`.

Comment: convert `NSString` to `NSDate`. **About 36,100 results (0.17 seconds)** (Source:Google).